# How to do a loop with a condition on all interations?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

```
CLUSTER | COLUMN_X
------------------
1       | yes
------------------
1       | no
------------------
2       | yes
------------------
2       | yes
------------------
3       | no
------------------
3       | no
```

I'd like to loop over the rows for which the cluster has at least one row with 'yes' as a value. Something like :

```
for row in (rows of the clusters for which there is a 'yes'):
    df['OUTPUT'][row] = 'ok'
for row not in (rows of the clusters for which there is a 'yes') :
    df['OUTPUT'][row] = 'not ok'
```

This is the expected output :

```
CLUSTER | COLUMN_X | OUTPUT
-----------------------------
1       | yes      | ok
-----------------------------
1       | no       | ok
-----------------------------
2       | yes      | ok
-----------------------------
2       | yes      | ok
-----------------------------
3       | no       | not ok
-----------------------------
3       | no       | not ok
```

Comment: You're using pandas so some hints; you should _not_ be thinking in terms of explicit loops. What you want here is `groupby` for `cluster` and set a value based on the count of `yes` in `COLUMN_X`.

Answer (score 1):

I am tired of using `transform` and `any` like below

```
df.COLUMN_X.eq('yes').groupby(df.CLUSTER).transform('any').map({True:'Ok',False:'not ok'})
```

So we try something new `isin`

```
s=df.loc[df.COLUMN_X.eq('yes'),'CLUSTER']
df['OUTPUT']='Not Ok'
df.loc[df.CLUSTER.isin(s),'OUTPUT']='ok'
df
Out[1191]: 
   CLUSTER COLUMN_X  OUTPUT
0        1      yes      ok
1        1       no      ok
2        2      yes      ok
3        2      yes      ok
4        3       no  Not Ok
5        3       no  Not Ok
```